# Using IBM WAS 8.5.5.9 and JAVA-8, but EJB 2.1 is not getting deployed giving error

Tags: java-8, websphere, ejb-2.x

**Using IBM WAS 8.5.5.9 and JAVA-8, but EJB 2.1 is not getting deployed giving error.**

```
failed with exception: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: Bean class 
    com.abc.def.EJSLocalStatelessEmployeeEjb_4333dc could not be found or loaded
at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.EJBMDOrchestrator.loadGeneratedImplementationClasses    
    (EJBMDOrchestrator.java:4858)
at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.EJBMDOrchestrator.finishBMDInitWithReferenceContext 
    (EJBMDOrchestrator.java:1076)
```

Please provide help, thanks.

Comment: IBM make hundreds of products so which product version 8.5.5.9 is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Guest is accurate.  EJBDeploy in WAS 8.5.5.9 is not usable with Java 8.  The limitation was documented here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rtrb_ejbdeploy390.html

The underlying library updates required to run EJBDeploy with Java 8 were too extensive and disruptive for a service stream.  Full support with EJBDeploy and Java 8 are provided in the updated v9 of WebSphere Application Server.

Comment: The workaround is to use Java 7 during your EJBDeploy processing.  You can then use Java 8 in your WebSphere runtime environment.  It's just the execution of EJBDeploy that doesn't support Java 8.  The generated artifacts will work just fine in a Java 8 runtime.

Comment: Kevin S, we are have one application ear this ear code is compiled and created by using JAVA-8, this ear having EJB 2.1 and other web related stuff.                                                                                                                       Want to deploy this ear with EJB 2.1 on IBM WAS 8559 having Java-8. How can we do that separately, means EJB 2.1 on Java 7 and rest on Java-8? Can you please explain more on this or provide steps.

Comment: You would use Java 7 during your build process, which would include the ejbdeploy processing.  Your WAS 8559 installation would be configured with Java 8 via the managesdk command.  Thus, the resulting output from your build and ejbdeploy using Java 7 can still be run with the Java 8 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The Known limitations in the product beta page in the Knowledge Center for WebSphere Application Server 9.0 beta states "EJBDeploy does not support previously existing enterprise beans with Java 8". I can't find mention of this restriction in the Knowledge Center for WebSphere Application Server 8.5, but it would not surprise me if the restriction is there.

Comment: Is this a copy/paste of my comment from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204639/installing-ear-application-having-ejbs-2-1-on-ibm-was-8-5-5-9-with-java8-of-ib)?